# Is it possible to make this change to a Rails table?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I accidentally created a Rails (Rails 4.2 with Postgres 9.4) table with the following:

```
class OrderDiscounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      create_table :order_discounts, id: false do |t|
        t.integer :order_id, primary: true
        t.integer :location_id
```

and wanted to have done it like this (ie have standard it table be a primary key and order_id just being a regular column):

```
class OrderDiscounts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
      create_table :order_discounts do |t|
        t.integer :order_id
        t.integer :location_id
```

I have already deployed to production (although no rows in this table yet). What would be the Rails migration to achieve this?

Comment: Are there other columns in this table? If not, it seems like a straight "look up" table and would not, necessarily need a primary key. If there are other columns, however, it seems as though it would necessitate a slightly different approach.

Comment: so I agree that in principe it might not need the standard primary key. But since we don't have any records, I would rather convert it in case things change down the road.

Comment: Cool ... just wanted to ask before supplying a suggestion/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few options to accomplish your task.

First, [rollback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#rolling-back) on production. Edit your migration (removing `primary: true`) and redeploy, running migrations.

Second, drop and recreate your table in a new migration.

```
class AwesomeMigration < ActicveRecord::Migration
  def change 
    drop_table :order_discounts 
    create_table :order_discounts do |t|
      t.integer :order_id
      t.integer :location_id 
      t.timestamps null: false # or drop this altogether if you don't want created_at and updated_at cols 
    end
  end 
end
```

Third, alter the table in a new migration

```
class AwesomeMigration < ActicveRecord::Migration
  def change 
    change_column :order_discounts, :order_id, :integer, primary_key: false 
    add_column :order_discounts, :id, :integer, primary_key: true
  end 
end
```

I believe any of those three would accomplish the end goal.